# Can all cubic/quartic polynomials be expressed in a form with only one x term?

Tags: polynomials, cubics

Quadratic expressions $ax^2+bx+c$ can all be expressed in a form with only one x term:

$$a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+c-\frac {b^2}{4a}$$

Is the same true for all cubic or quartic expressions?

Is there a name for this property (expressable in a form with only one x term)?

Comment: I do know that the roots of all cubics can be solved using completion of the cube. It runs along the same lines as what youre talking about with the quadratic. But no, you cannot express all cubics as $a(x+b)^3 + c$.

Answer (score 2):

Your only choice to reach third degree would be $a(x+b)^3+c$, which has only three degrees of freedom when four are neede for the general cubic. Specifically, $x^3+x$ cannot be obtained this way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "in a form with only one $x$ term", probably not.

If you mean to ask whether cubic polynomials can (analogously to the *[vertex form](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/sqrvertx.htm)* you've written for the quadratic) all be written in the form
$$A(x - B)^3 + C, \qquad (\ast)$$
the answer is definitely no: The expression only has three real parameters, but the general cubic depends on four (the coefficients of the four powers of $x$ that occur). One can, however, write a cubic polynomial
$$a x^3 + b x^2 + c + d,$$
as a cubic polynomial
$$a \left(x + \frac{b}{3a} x\right)^3 + c' \left(x + \frac{b}{3a}\right) + d',$$
in $\left(x + \frac{b}{3a}\right)$ and which in particular has no quadratic term in that expression.

The statements for quartic (and higher-degree) polynomials are analogous.

I don't know of any special name for polynomials of the form $(\ast)$, but observe that a cubic polynomial has this form exactly if its roots form an equilateral triangle in the complex plane (centered at $B$ in fact): If $B + z$ is one solution to $(x - B)^3 = -\frac{C}{A}$, then the three roots are
$$B + z, \qquad \omega(B + z), \qquad \omega^2(B + z),$$
where $\omega$ is a nontrivial third root of unity.
Likewise, a polynomial of degree $n > 3$ can be written in the form $(\ast)$, where we replace the exponent $3$ with $n$, if its roots are the vertices of some regular $n$-gon in the complex plane. In particular, any such polynomial can have at most two roots.